# Инициализация класса внутри шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс:

```
template <class T>
class cFunction {
public:
    cFunction(cArguments* args, int _n);
    float getY(int num);
private:
    T* func;
};
```

и есть класс:

```
class cFunction1 {
public:
    cFunction1(float _a, float _b, float _x);
    float getY();
private:
    float a, b, x;
};
```

который может передаваться в качестве параметра для класса cFunction.

Конструктор класса cFunction:

```
template <class T>
cFunction<T>::cFunction(cArguments *args, int _n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _n; i++) {
        func[i] = new T(args->getA(), args->getB(), args->getX());
    }
}
```

Среда на такое не ругается, ибо судя по всему C++ допускает такое, но я так полагаю, что это неверно с логической точки зрения, ибо в качестве параметра класса может быть передан другой класс, у которого нет подобного конструктора. Как можно сделать подобное грамотно? Где то слышал, что делается это в теле условного оператора, только как именно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Правильно (во **всех** случаях) аналогичная логика реализована в шаблоне [`boost::function,`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/function/reference.html#header.boost.function_hpp) и, соответственно, `std::function`.

  > Естественно, что там есть куча мелких, но важных деталей, но общий подход строится на использовании [`variadic templates`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) (или эмулировании их при помощи `(T1 t1, T2 t2, ..., T25 t25))`, [`SFINAE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) и аккуратных `type cast'ах` и специализациях для `function pointer` типов.
- Писать такое самостоятельно лично я смысла не вижу.
- В плане создания объектов я пользуюсь следующими `rule of thumb:`

  > - В ходе шаблонов недопустимы вызовы конструкторов для типов, не являющихся [`DefaultConstructible,`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/DefaultConstructible.html) а допустимость `DefaultConstructible` типов должна быть явно отражена в контракте шаблона (ввиду того, что это *нельзя проверить* с помощью `static_assert'ов` [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733377/is-there-a-way-to-test-whether-a-c-class-has-a-default-constructor-other-than) [[2]](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/detail/has_default_constructor.hpp).
  > - Любая логика конструирования объектов, если она требуется, переносится в специализированные фабрики / вспомогательные классы.